# Is there a way to get both a useful and type knowledge from a type predicate in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, validation, types

When validating data, sometimes one wants:
 - whether the data is valid
 - if not, the validation errors

Can we do this in a natural, JS-y way in TypeScript? Does something like the following work?

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    height: number,
};

function validatePerson(obj: object): obj is Person & string[] {

    const missingKeys = ["dependencies", "name"]
        .filter(key => key in obj)
        .map(key => `key ${key} is missing from obj`);

    if (!missingKeys.length) {
        return missingKeys as typeof missingKeys & true;
    }
    else {
        return missingKeys as typeof missingKeys & false;
    }
}

const x = { name: "ff", height: getHeight()};
const validationErrors = validatePerson(x);
if (!validationErrors.length) {
    const b: Person = x;
}

function getHeight(): any {
    return 40;
}
```

The best thing I can get to actually work is this weird pointer-passing-style thing, but it just isn't JS-y enough for me to want this on `master`:

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    height: number,
};

function validatePerson(obj: object, placeToPushValidationErrors: string[]): obj is Person {

    const missingKeys = ["dependencies", "name"]
        .filter(key => key in obj)
        .map(key => `key ${key} is missing from obj`);

    placeToPushValidationErrors.push(...missingKeys);

    return !missingKeys.length;
}

// imagine this is coming from untrustworthy JSON
function getHeight(): unknown {
    return 40;
}

const person = { name: "ff", height: getHeight() };
const validationErrors = [];
if (validatePerson(person, validationErrors)) {
    const p: Person = person;
}
else {
    throw Error(`invalid person: ${validationErrors.join(', ')}`)
}
```

Comment: Nope, a custom type-guard must return `param is type`. You can return `Person | string[]` put it in a variable and use `if( usa_bbox instanceof Array) `

Comment: Unfortunately, user-defined type guard types of the form x is Y are not really first-class citizens and can't move around or compose the way other types can. So you can't return something like `{isValid: obj is Person, validationErrors: string[]}`. You could give up on type guards and return something like `{person?: Person, validationErrors: string[]}` and then use whether or not the `person` property is defined as a guard.

Comment: @jcalz if you make your comment an answer I'll mark it correct. That's a really interesting suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use type predicates for this, unfortunately.  They aren't usable in unions, intersections, or as object property types.  The only place they can really appear is as the return type for a function and they are tied to exactly one parameter passed into the function.  And type predicates are related to `boolean` in a way you don't want here, since you'd like the return value type to be an array but `true` and `false` are not arrays.

Anyway, I'd suggest doing something different here... return an object containing both the array you want and *optionally* a `Person`.  If the `Person` is present, then the validation succeeded; otherwise use the validation error array:

```
function validatePerson(obj: object) {

  const validationErrors = ["dependencies", "name"]
    .filter(key => key in obj)
    .map(key => `key ${key} is missing from obj`);

  const ret: { person?: Person, validationErrors: string[] } = { validationErrors };

  if (validationErrors.length === 0) {
    ret.person = obj as Person;
  }
  return ret;

}

declare const x: object;
const validatedPerson = validatePerson(x);

if (validatedPerson.person) {
  const b: Person = validatedPerson.person
} else {
  throw Error(`invalid person: ${validatedPerson.validationErrors.join(', ')}`)
}
```

So you're using `validatedPerson.person` as a type guard and it narrows automatically for you.

---

An even more succinct solution is to do what @TitianCernicova-Dragomir suggested and return either a `Person` or an error array:

```
function validatePerson(obj: object) {
  const validationErrors = ["dependencies", "name"]
    .filter(key => key in obj)
    .map(key => `key ${key} is missing from obj`);
  return (validationErrors.length) ? validationErrors : (obj as Person);
}

declare const x: object;
const validatedPerson = validatePerson(x);

if (!Array.isArray(validatedPerson)) {
  const b: Person = validatedPerson;
} else {
  throw Error(`invalid person: ${validatedPerson.join(', ')}`)
}
```

Now the return type of `validatePerson()` is `Person | string[]`.  Then you use whether or not the return type is an array as a type guard and it all works.

---

Hope those give you some ideas on how to move forward.  Good luck!